# Did I just 'autoremove' half my computer?

Tags: apt, 15.04, python

I am trying to get Django/Python to run on my computer, but it's confusing that `python` runs Python v2 while there is also a Python v3 installed which needs to be run as `python3` (both come preinstalled?!) and either way, the Django installer complains.

**Anyway,** I was trying to remove Django and the Python PIP installation utility, so **I ran the command: `sudo apt-get autoremove python-pip*`** and the terminal output frankly scares me: http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=b0RHs3e4

It looks like it removed all kinds of things I didn't expect, including obviously vital and non-Python things like `ubuntu-desktop` and `unity8-common` **and even `software-center`!**

I'm afraid that if I log out of my session or reboot, then I'll never get this computer started again.

**What damage did I just do, and how can I recover?** Why where all of these removed in the first place? How did "autoremove" trigger these to be included? (Luckily, my actual data is safely backed up.)

**Update 1:**
The answer linked in the comment below looks relevant *but not complete.*  Following the linked answer, my system did reinstall many packages as expected -- but others were not, so they are still missing from my system. Still worried whether my machine is broken. Among the removed-and-not-reinstalled packages are:

- account-plugin-tools
- accountsservice-ubuntu-schemas
- address-book-service
- dbus-property-service
- dcraw
- exiftran
- ffmpegthumbnailer
- libhardware2
- libhybris
- libmedia1
- libmirplatform6
- libmirserver30
- libpay2
- system-image-common
- system-image-dbus
- unity-plugin-scopes
- unity-scope-scopes
- unity8-common
- urfkill
- xcftools
- ... and many others

Can I just reinstall these with `apt-get` as well?

**Update 2:**
As suggested in comments, I will now do `sudo apt-get install --install-suggests {my list of removed packages}`. Curiously, even core things like `software-center` were removed and are not even suggested. So I must include those explicitly in my command.

And I'm still afraid to reboot my computer. I hate it when I make nasty mistakes like this one, because I'm not guru enough to feel safe that I reliably fixed it again.

Comment: You should be able to copy the lines after "the following packages will be REMOVED:", and paste a command `sudo apt-get install ` in front of them. The package `apt` itself does not depend on python, as far as I can tell.

Comment: @muru thanks for the dupe candidate, however I find that it doesn't cover it because there is a lot more still missing. I updated my question.

Comment: Some of those maybe recommended dependencies of `ubuntu-desktop`. Try with `--install-recommends` or `--install-suggests`.

Comment: I added "update 2". Thanks especially to @Jos!

Comment: The `software-center` is not widely considered a core application. It is not much more than a front end for the `apt` and `aptitude` packages. Your system will not stop working without it.